# How can I make sure that the threads are executing in order?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose that I have created three threads using Runnable Class.

```
MyThread t1 = new Mythread("T1");

Mythread t2 = new MyThread("T2");

MyThread t3 = new MyThread("T3");
```

My question is how can I make sure that t1,t2,t3 are executed in order using **join() method?**

Join() method is used to stop the current thread(Main thread) and execute thread upon which join has been called.

Like this --> **t1.t.join();**

Now suppose I that I will call join() on another thread

Like this --> **t2.t.join();**

Now which thread will be stopped and could please explain your answer?

Comment: you could assign priority to thread in the highest to lowest order of execution.

Comment: @KumarKailash That is not the purpose of thread priorities